# Cant save environmental variables with set .env file

Tags: python, node.js, environment-variables, solidity

My .env file contains this

> set WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID=https://mainnet.infura.io set
> ETHERSCAN_TOKEN=ATS8
> set PRIVATE_KEY="0x"

I previously ran "set .env" and also individually used set for each var but I had to reinstall my project and save these variables again and when i call my script it says that the vars aren't set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.env` file usually contains variable names and values without the `set` expression.

A value should not be wrapped in quotes `"`. If it contains a space, write it simply with a space (e.g. `TEXT=Lorem ipsum`).

```
WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID=https://mainnet.infura.io
ETHERSCAN_TOKEN=ATS8
PRIVATE_KEY=0x
```